# c++ pair template struct declaration ambiguity!

Tags: c++, templates, definition, ambiguity, std-pair

In definition of pair class in c++ there are two typedefs. what are they for? there are no use of them in the code!

```
template <class T1, class T2> struct pair
{
  typedef T1 first_type;
  typedef T2 second_type;

  T1 first;
  T2 second;
  pair() : first(T1()), second(T2()) {}
  pair(const T1& x, const T2& y) : first(x), second(y) {}
  template <class U, class V>
    pair (const pair<U,V> &p) : first(p.first), second(p.second) { }
}
```

Comment: No use in *what* code? What specific body of code did you inspect in order to come to the conclusion that these typedefs are not used?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are just here for you convenience, so you can use them in your code. C++ doesn't have a reflection model , so that's the only way you have "know" what types they are
Suppose you define your own pair

> typedef pair MyPair;

Then you can use

> MyPair::first_type
>   MyPair::second_type

for example,

```
MyPair::first_type my_first(MyPair& pair)
{
    return pair.first;
}
```

Then you won't need to research and replace everywhere in your code , if you change the original definition of MyPair.

Answer (score 5):

It's to allow other pieces of code to declare variables of the types without having direct access to the type parameters (T1 & T2). A similar, less trivial, example are the typedefs in container classes:

```
vector<int>::iterator curNum;
for(curNum = someVect.begin(); curNum != someVect.end(); curNum++)
    ; //do stuff
```

This uses the typedef `iterator` defined in the vector template to create `curNum`. It will be somewhat less useful come C++0x's `auto` keyword:

```
for(auto curNum = someVect.begin(); curNum != someVect.end(); curNum++)
    ;
```

Answer (score 3):

This is so you can refer to the types in your code using e.g. `pair<int,string>::first_type myVariable`, or if you've typedef'd a particular flavour of the template then `MyPair::first_type myVariable`.

Answer (score 1):

They are public aliases of the passed-in T1 and T2 types that can be referenced after the object is constructed.